# Restore database password unicentapos

Tags: java, mysql, pos, unicenta

So we are running a opensource pos project named "chromispos" based on unicenta. Sadly we have lost the database root password and we would like to retrieve it. The database runs locally with wampp in MySQL. I know the fact it is possible to change the database password for the root user but since we cannot change the password again in the POS software it will not connect anymore.

Is there anyway I can retrieve the password? This is the source file of the en/decryption:
https://github.com/micolous/Openbravo/blob/master/src-pos/com/openbravo/pos/forms/AppViewConnection.java

The hash to be decrypted:
crypt:6FF1981268FBCD0CBB9DB2A39005780D

Answer (score 0):

The root password will be stored somewhere in chromispos if that is still operational.

Alternately create a new database user with the same access level and use this as the user root access. After starting with skip-grant-tables, copy the root user row from mysql.user changing the username and password columns.